# maximum numbers which can be sent in kannel

Tags: php, kannel

I have setup a kannel and sending SMS using HTTP interface. I have tried sending SMS to 2 numbers. My question is how many numbers can I send-to in single URL.

Answer (score 1):

Ron as per my experience I have test this with **1638 number** don't worry kannel is enough powerful to handle large request.

just add your number in this format

```
http://yourhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=demo&password=demo&to=919907723199+919981534313&from=919981534313&text=Rahul+SS+helo&dlr-mask=31&dlr-url=http
```